# X be a countably infinite discrete topological space homeomorphic to the subspace Y of R with usual topology. which of the following can be Y?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, rational-numbers

> Let $X$ be a countably infinite discrete topological space which is
> homeomorphic to the subspace $Y$ of $\mathbb R$ with usual
> topology.Then which of the following can be $Y$?
>
> $(i)\mathbb Q$
>
> $(ii)\mathbb Z$
>
> $(iii)\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$
>
> $(iv)\mathbb N$

$Y$ being a subspace of $\mathbb R$ is a hausdorff space.
All$(i),(ii),(iv)$ are hausdorff with the usual topology but $(iii)$ is not hausdorff as it is not possible to separate $\{0\}$ from $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}$.But ,
$X$ is a countably infinite discrete topological space ,so it will also be a hausdorff space.

Hence it will not be possible to establish the homoemorphism between $X$ and $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}$.

So,the only possibilities $Y$ to be $\mathbb Q$,$\mathbb Z$,$\mathbb N$

Please verify my arguments

Comment: Hint:  Discreteness is an invariant.

Comment: You haven’t covered discrete-ness. Is $\Bbb Q$ discrete? Why/why not? Are $\Bbb Z,\Bbb N$ discrete?

Comment: @FShrike:$\mathbb Q$ equipped with usual topology is not discrete

Comment: **$(iii) $ isn't Hausdorff** . Do you know that **Hausdorffness" is a "hereditary property"?

Comment: @P.Styles Do you know homepmorphic image of a discrete space is discrete?

Comment: @P.Styles Right. So why do you think $\Bbb Q$ is an option? See Randall’s comment

Comment: @FShrike: discreteness did'nt clicked my mind...

Comment: @SouravGhosh: yes ,hausdorffness is a hereditary property..means have given the wrong argument as $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in N\}\cup \{0\}$ is a hausdorff space (subsapce of $\mathbb R$)

Comment: Review the def'n of Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. $f:(X,\tau)\to (Y, \tau')$ be a homeomorphism and $(X, \tau) $ is a discrete space.Then $(Y, \tau') $ is also discrete.

( What you know about the open sets of two homeomorphic spaces? )

2. Any map define on a discrete space is continuous.

(What happen if a we take a bijective map and domain, codomain both are discrete space?)

> Any two discrete space where the underlying sets have the same cardinality are homeomorphic.(Can you find a homeomorphism?)

3. Suppose $(Y, \tau')$ is a topological subspace of $ (X, \tau)$.Then $A\in\tau'$ iff $\exists U\in\tau$ such that $A=Y\cap U$ .
4. Prove $\Bbb{N}, \Bbb{Z}$ are discrete space as euclidean subspace.

It's enough to show that every singleton sets are open in the subspace topology. (Why?)

For an example $\{5\}=\Bbb{N}\cap(4, 6)$

$\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\Bbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}, \Bbb{Q}$ are not discrete.

Is $\{0\}$ open in the euclidean subspace $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\Bbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$ ? Do you know Archimedean property of real?

For $\Bbb{Q}$ use the density of rationals among reals.

Comment: :$\{0\}$ is not discrete in $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \mathbb \{0\}$ because the open sets in  $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \mathbb \{0\}$ will be of the form $(0,1/m)$ and $\{0\}\neq (\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{0\})\cap (0,1/m)$

Comment: $\{0\}$ isn't open. Yes. Do you know for any $\epsilon>p, \exists n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Yes, know archimedean property

Comment: Hence any open interval containing $0$ conatins a point of the set $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\Bbb{N}\}$. In other words $0$ isn't an interior point of the set $\{0\}$ .Hence $\{0\}$ is not an open set

Comment: @Sorab Ghosh: Is my argument correct for discreetness?

Comment: We have to show $\{0\}$ is not open.

Comment: I get your point that {0} is open in X but {0} is not open in $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$,but i want to know about my argument of discreetness...is it correct?

Comment: To prove $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$ isn't discrete it is enough to show that $\{0\}$ isn't open in the subspace.  Open sets are of the form $ (a, b) \cap \{\frac{1}{n}\}$